# Laravel Eloquent update created_at value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I need to change a post created_at because i send sms to posts created at this month according to created_at. When i try with this created_at does not change value!

```
public function Controller(Posts $post){
    $post->update(['created_at'=>Carbon::today()]);
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't say to update the created_at - try e.g. `->update('created_at', Carbon::now())` or similar.

Comment: @JoelHinz not work

Answer (score 10):

`created_at` is not typically [mass assigned](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) like that.  You probably need to add it to the `$fillable` attribute on your `Post` model, eg:

```
protected $fillable = [...., 'created_at'];
```

Note that as someone else pointed out, `Carbon::today()` does not seem like the right thing to use - it works and gives a valid timestamp, but the timestamp is for midnight.  You probably want [`Carbon::now()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), if you really want the actual time of the change.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function Controller(Posts $post){
      $post->created_at = Carbon::today();
      $post->save(['timestamps' => false]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Carbon::today()` is not actually generating a valid timestamp. You need to use `Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString()` to get a valid timestamp.

Updated snippet:

```
public function Controller(Posts $post){
    $post->update(['created_at' => Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **$guarded** to allow all other attributes to be fillable

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

See eloquent documentation on [GuardsAttributes](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.html)